# C Web Server Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, http, web, webserver

I am having some trouble understanding why I am getting a segmentation fault in my homemade web server. I am trying to correctly label the content type for .html and .txt documents. I can open an .html file in my web browser just fine when my server is running. However, my server is closing on a segmentation fault when I try to open a .txt document. The code below is where I am getting the issue.

```
void* thread_runner(void* sockfd)
{
    char buffer[256];
    int n;
    int sock = *(int*)sockfd;
    bzero(buffer,256);
    char filename[256];
    bzero(filename,256);
        n = read(sock,filename,255);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

    FILE *fp;
    char file[4096];
    char* word = strtok(filename, " ");
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    word++;
    printf("filename = \"%s\"\n", word);
    fp = fopen(word, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("file pointer is NULL\n");
        return 0;
    }
    char string[4096];
    char* extension;
    bzero(string, 4096);
    bzero(file, 4096);
    char* word2;
    word2 = strtok(word, ".");
    while ((word2 = strtok(NULL, ".")) != NULL)
    {
        extension = word2;
    }
    printf("File Extension: %s\n", extension);
    if (strncmp(extension, "html", 4096) == 0) {
        printf("HTML FILE FOUND\n");
        strcat(string, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Length: 4096    \nConnection: keep-alive\n\n");
    }

    else if (strncmp(extension, "txt", 4096) == 0) {
        printf("TXT FILE FOUND\n");
        strcat(string, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/plain\nContent-Length: 4096\nConnection: keep-alive\n\n");
    }
```

the error occurs in this loop.
I have used bzero on 'string'.

```
    while (fgets(file, 4096, fp))
    {
        strcat(string, file);
    }
    //printf("Sending text:%s", string);
    printf("The requested file was: %s.%s\n",word,extension);
    n = write(sock,string,4096);
    printf("file contents are %s\n", string);
    fclose(fp);



    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
    if (n == 0)
    {
        close(sock);
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged line by line to see what’s happening? Is your file under 4k? Why are you always sending 4k even if the data is less?

Comment: What is `word++` for? That skips over the first character of the filename.

Comment: 1) You've use "strcat()" several times.  What happens if you overflow 4096? Where are you checking to ensure that doesn't happen?  2) "Magic numbers" like `char string[4096];` and `bzero(string, 4096);` are "bad".  Consider using `#define MAXLEN 4096`, `const int MAXLEN = 4096;`, `sizeof (string)` or equivalent instead. instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing past the end of `string`. `string` only has 4096 characters in it, but your loop tries to read the entire file into it when it keeps calling `strcat()` in a loop.

Instead of concatenating the entire file into a variable and then writing it all, use `fread()` to read the file in chunks and immediately write them to the socket. There's no need to read line by line.

```
size_t in;
while ((in = fread(file, 1, sizeof file, fp) > 0) {
    int n = write(sock, file, in);
    if (n < in) {
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    }
}
close(sock);
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: I'm now getting a blank page when I try to load up the .html

Comment: For complete error checking `ferror()` should be called right after the `while`-loop.

Comment: @tyler7410 Have you tried running the server under a debugger to see what it's doing? I think this code is pretty simple and should work.